# roll-over script not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a mouse roll-over. i.e when user places the pointer on the image mouse over event is triggered and the next image from the array comes over.But nothing is happening when i am running this script :

```
window.onload = startRollOver;

var pictures = new  Array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg");
var i = 0;

function startRollOver() {
document.getElementById("picture").src.onmouseover = createRollOver();
}

function createRollOver() {
if(i<=7)
   return pictures[i++];
 if(i>7) {
    i=0;
    return pictures[i];
 }
}
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.src.onmouseover` does not make much sense. You should assign a function to `onmouseover` so that the function gets called when the mouse moves over the element:

```
document.getElementById("picture").onmouseover = function() { // is executed when mouse is over element
    this.src = createRollOver(); // each time it is called, change the src
};
```

Also, you can use a more convenient way of declaring arrays:

```
["1.jpg", "2.jpg", ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting "onmouseover" on the string "src" instead of on the DOM element. You need to set the event on the DOM element.

```
window.onload=startRollOver;

function startRollOver() {
    document.getElementById("picture").onmouseover = function (e) {
        e.target.src = createRollOver();
    };
}

function createRollOver() {
    // ...
}
```